# sqoop to teradata - How can i run a 300 lines of query on teradata from hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop

I have a project where I have to run the 300 lines of sql query on Teradata.
Sql query basically creates a table and using some updates from other tables it will insert the data into the table that is created at the beginning at the end there is a select statement that will basically pull the data in the columns that we required.

My question here is how can I run that 300 lines from Hadoop ?
I tried doing with **sqoop eval** which looks like  `sqoop eval -libjars /var/lib/sqoop/terajdbc4.jar,/var/lib/sqoop/tdgssconfig.jar --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver --connect (connection parameters) --query "300line of query"`  **It is throwing me this error as**

`WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
17/01/30 15:05:53 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
17/01/30 15:05:54 WARN tool.EvalSqlTool: SQL exception executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.14] [Error 3576] [SQLState 25000] Data definition not valid unless solitary.
.`

What is solitary ?

My plan is to run the query through sqoop eval and using sqoop import I will import the table into Hadoop. Advice me if this is the right way to do this process or if there is any other best approach to do this ?

Answer (score -1):

By any chance you have DDL statement in your query? [here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/General_Reference/B035_1096_109A/Database.05.0844.html) you may find the reason why it is throwing error.